# Javascript always exiting abruptly without giving any error

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code and I am just not able to understand why my script is exiting abruptly at the function call to localCompare below:

```
var results = [
        {
            "ID": 5,
            "Name": "Project Management",
            "ParentID": 1,
            "UserID": 2
        },
        {
             "ID": 7,
             "Name": "Javascript",
             "ParentID": 1,
             "UserID": 2
        }

    ];


    $("#addNewPage").click(function () {
        var url = $("#pageURL").val();
        var tagnames = $("#tags").val().split(",");
        var tagData = [];
        var tagInfo;
        for (var i = 0; i < tagnames.length; i++) {
            tagName = tagnames[i];
            var j=0;
            for (; j < results.length; j++) {
                if (!(tagname.localeCompare(results[j].Name))) {
                    tagInfo = results[j];
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if(j == results.length){
                tagInfo.ID = "0";
                tagInfo.Name = tagName;
                tagInfo.ParentID = "0";
                tagInfo.UserID = "2";
            }

            tagData[tagData.length] = tagInfo;
        }
     }
```

I am new to web development so unable to find ways to debug this problem. Can some one help what tools could be used when running into such problems? I am using Chrome to test this.

The code is available at JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pud25ffd/2/

Comment: Did you switch on the JS console? (Ctrl-Shift-K)

Comment: Could you complete your code (with some html particularly) so that community can reproduce your issue ? Your question is lacking details at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was due to incorrect variable name.